# RegEx continuous validation for a specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression match in JavaScript for a string like [any four digits][single hyphen][three alphanumeric characters]. The validation should happen continuously. That means partial mach also should return true.

I was able to validate strings like [any four digits][single hyphen] 

1232- 
4323- 
But I'm not able to validate the [three alphanumeric] part

following is my regex for first two parts

```
let reg = /^[[0-9.\-]{1,6}]$/;
```

Successful validation is expected on strings such as

```
3432-ad3
6548-333
7654-2d1
5649-dse
```

Comment: Why not? What specifically are you unable to figure out?

Comment: Hi I'm not able to concatenate the last part (alphanumeric)

Comment: Why not? What part of the required regex isn't working? Btw, the hyphen shouldn't be in the allowable character range, since you presumably don't want 1-2-34. Seems like you're just not grouping your actual groups, you're trying to do it all in a single character range, inside... a character range? I'd strongly recommend just taking the time to learn some regex basics.

Answer (score 0):

`\d{4}` matches 4 digits,
`\-` matches - literally
`\w{3}` matches 3 of [a-zA-Z0-9_]

```
^\d{4}\-\w{3}$
```

UPDATED:
the `\w`would match other chars other than A-Z0-9 so

```
^\d{4}\-[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$
```

would be more correct

To match the cases where you have nothing after the -:

```
^\d{4}\-([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?$
```

`([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})` - is a group matching 3 of a-zA-Z0-9
`?` is the quantifier matching none or exactly one of that group

Comment: Hi thanks for the input .. this also works but it returns true only after we type the complete string. what i was expecting that even if we type the part of the string in the expected format it should return true. (1234- true, 4358-a true, 3343-d33 true

Comment: ah okay, then you can modify then quantifier, {3} indicates exactly 3 of them. but you can also place {,3} indicating none to 3.
Or if you want exactly none or 3 of them I believe you can do by `^\d{4}\-([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?$`

Comment: @LalasMuathasim You're not being very clear. Do you want *continuous validation*, e.g., this string *may* be valid, from beginning to end? IMO you should just open a new question and trash this one, because your current requirement is *significantly* different than what you asked.

Comment: @dave Newton .. Yes it has to be continuous validation i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can design/modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/y6CavS/1/). You might want to write an expression similar to:

```
[0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{3}
```

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

```js
const regex = /[0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{3}/gm;
const str = `3432-ad3 
6548-333 
7654-2d1 
5649-dse `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}$
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `[0-9]{4}` - allows only numbers (characters 0 through 9) and only 4 of them
- `-` - dash character
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}` - allows numbers (0 through 9), lowercase letters (a - z), or uppercase letters (A - Z) and only 3 of any of those.
- `$` - End of string

Comment: Hi thanks for the input .. this works but it returns true only after we type the complete string. what i was expecting that even if we type the part of the string in the expected format it should return true. (1234- true, 4358-a true, 3343-d33 true)

Comment: @LalasMuathasim That's a *completely* separate issue, and orthogonal, since you're now asking for *partial* regex matching. You don't want a regex, you want a state machine that understands if the input *could* be valid, even if it isn't complete yet. That's a very different problem.